# Simple android app (in flash) teleports between frames

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

So I am trying to make a small android app. I have two frames, one with "start" and one with "rules" I only have code on the first one which is:
(The start button has an instance and symbol of `start`)
        /* Tap Event

```
Instructions:
1. Add your custom code on a new line after the line that says "// Start your custom code" below.
The code will execute when the symbol instance is tapped.
*/

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

start.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler_2);

function fl_TapHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    // Start your custom code
    // This example code reduces the transparency of the object by half upon each tap event
    start.alpha *= 0.5;
    gotoAndStop(2);
    trace("going to 2")
    start.alpha *= 2;
    // End your custom code
}
```

When I run it, the emulator teleports between frames, like it usually does if there **is a compiler error**. However, when I look at the compiler errors, it does not say anything. Is there a problem *already* or is it happening because there is no code on the second frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[1]** Add `stop()` in the first frame.

**[2]** Either remove

```
Instructions:
1. Add your custom code on a new line after the line that says "// Start your custom code" below.
The code will execute when the symbol instance is tapped.
*/
```

or change it to

```
/*Instructions:
1. Add your custom code on a new line after the line that says "// Start your custom code" below.
The code will execute when the symbol instance is tapped.
*/
```

**[3]** Make sure no errors are being **outputted.**

Comment: Thanks! This works. Although now, clicking on the "start" button will give me an error before going to the next frame. http://i.imgur.com/3mybMCS.png

Comment: @user2789610 No, you have to enable touch on the simulator.  Also, you seem glad, so you can upvote my answer.

Comment: I did... Still get the same issue.

Comment: @user2789610 Weird.  Make sure `start` is on both frames.  If it's not, it means `start is null`.